# How to recover folder overwritten by `mv` command in ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, data-recovery, wsl2

How to recover folder overwritten by `mv` command in `Ubuntu-20.04` on `wsl2`?
I was moving two folders, `folderA` and `folderB` from `current directory` to `dest`.

Here is what I did:

```
mv folderA ./dest/folderA
```

---

```
mv folderB ./dest/folderA
```

*This where I made a mistake. I have accidentally overwritten* `folderA` *with the contents of* `folderB`

I'm left with `folderA` with the contents of `folderB`.

How to recover the `folderA` and/or its contents?

Comment: Check `./dest/folderA/folderB`. You may have overwritten something if the original `folderA` contained a directory named `folderB`, I think. Is this the case?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thank you! I thought it was all gone, but it's just residin inside `folderA`. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The `mv` command does not overwrite folders.

*If* `folderA` was indeed a folder and *if* you have indeed performed exactly the command sequence

```
mv folderA ./dest/folderA
mv folderB ./dest/folderA
```

then the second command has moved `folderB` *into* `./dest/folderA`.
That is, you'll find its content at `./dest/folderA/folderB`.

By the way, if `./dest/folderA` already existed before the first command then that first command will *also* have moved `folderA` *into* `./dest/folderA` so you'll find your two folders side by side as `./dest/folderA/folderA` and `./dest/folderA/folderB`.